# How can I convert numeric values to labels eg. (High Low) in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have [Kibana Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohQLl.png) that displays numerical values. I want to change it so if the value is higher than X it should display "High" or if lower than X it should display "Low"?

Eg. In this case [Kibana Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohQLl.png) I should see High since the value is greater than 4

Answer (score 0):

It might be not possible to show High or Low as text but you can change the colour. So for High you can show it Red Colour annd for Low you can show it in Green colour.

You can use [TSVB Visulization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tsvb.html) and add your condition in Panel option tab.
[image: Sample Configuration]